# Rails Devise gem: Limit the number of times I can resend confirmation mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a user admin who can create new user and the newly created user need to confirm the email against him in order to activate his account.

How can I limit the number of times a "confirmation mail is resend" against a particular user.

Say I created a new user and he hasn't confimed via his mail, so I send him another confirmation mail in case he lost the first one, like wise I can resend him mail as many time as I want. But I want this number to be restricted to say 5. So for a particular user the

`user.send_confirmation_instructions` can only be used 5 times.

Is there any devise inbuilt way of doing this.

Comment: No, there isn't any existing configuration for this scenario. One reason might be that you don't want to have an extra burden over your head to clear out the restriction for all the users who gets blocked after certain number of trials.

Comment: Hi @Surya thanks for responding. Can you suggest a way I can implement this, that you believe should be ideal and uses something that is pre-existing in devise ? or a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any inbuilt way in devise to handle this. But another simple approach that I can think of is

1. Add a `mail_counter` attribute in `user` model.
2. Increment this mail_counter by "1" for that particular user whenever `user.send_confirmation_instructions` is called.
3. Add an if condition of `user.mail_counter < 6` to execute before `user.send_confirmation_instructions` is called.

Comment: Hi @TarunJadhwani thats one obvious way, what I was looking for was something that not really this obvious. I feel thats the essence of the learning curve in ruby and rails. There is always a better approach.:). I appreciate your effort of answering it. Thank you